# What does rwk stands for?

Tags: apparmor

I just check `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

I saw,

```
/var/lib/mysql/** rwk, // what is rwk stand for ? Is it read, write?? then what does k stands for?
/var/log/mysql/ r,
```

What does `rwk` stands for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As documented under [File permissions](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#file-permissions):

> - r - read - permission to read data
> - w - write - permission to create, delete, write to a file and extend it
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - k - lock - permission to lock a file, is combined with write perm to determine if it has permission to take exclusive lock

Answer (score 2):

r stands for read, w for write and k for lock.